# What status codes raise Errno::ECONNRESET in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, http, httparty

Using HTTParty to make a GET request. How can I find out which HTTP responses raise `Errno::ECONNRESET`?

The error is no longer happening, so I would like to browse the code or some documentation.

Ruby Docs didn't help: http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/webrick/rdoc/Errno/ECONNRESET.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Errno::ECONNRESET isn't caused by an HTTP status code. It's thrown when the remote host closes the TCP connection prematurely.

Comment: There's a lot of things that can go wrong when making a remote connection and this is one of them. Always be prepared for the unexpected.